# How can we make an ASP.NET MVC4 route based on a subdomain?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting, routes

How can we make an ASP.NET MVC4 route that uses subdomain information to determine its route? For example:

`website1.domain.com` goes to `domain.com\websites\1`

`website2.domain.com` goes to `domain.com\websites\2`

This is a dynamic mapping like this: `websiteN.domain.com` goes to `domain.com\websites\N`

I have a username parameter,How Can I pass through  controller/action?

Comment: I looked for this exactly. don't think it can be done.

Comment: @DaveA: I just changed website1.domain.com goes to domain.com\websites\1 and website2.domain.com goes to domain.com\websites\2 ..., Sorry about that

Comment: OIC, thats more manageable

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET's built-in routing doesn't directly support sub-domain routing. But fortunately, there's [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/), which is a very popular add-on library for routing that allows you to do lots of fancy routing, including sub-domain routing.

Here's an example from the Attribute Routing site:

```
[RouteArea("Users", Subdomain = "users")]
public class SubdomainController : Controller
{
    [GET("")]
    public ActionResult Index() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I test it on localhost:[PortNumber]?

Comment: If you put some example here , I would really appreciate you.How I can use with my subdomains, you mentioned users.

Comment: @Houshang please check out the documentation on the AttributeRouting web site. The name "users" happens to be the sub-domain in this case, so for you it would be "website1".

Comment: would you be able to take a look on my question, Sorry about that, I just changed website1.domain.com goes to domain.com\websites\1 and website2.domain.com goes to domain.com\websites\2 ... , Can I do it again with your solution?